# If $G$ is a finite group, $H\vartriangleleft G$, $G/H$ is finite $p$-group and $H\subseteq Z\left(G\right)$, show that $[G,G]$ is $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group, $H\vartriangleleft G$, $G/H$ is finite $p$-group and $H\subseteq Z\left(G\right)$, show that $[G,G]$ is $p$-group.

Comment: You are still not providing any context. Are you familiar with the transfer homomorphism?

Comment: It is true under the weaker hypothesis that $G/H$ is finite. Then $[G,G]$ is a finite $p$-group. I don't know whether it is true if you don't assume $G/H$ finite!

Comment: Note that the assumption implies that $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group. So it suffices to consider the case $H = Z(G)$. I looked it up on google, and in the paper "On a Theorem of Schur" (2001), Peter Hilton shows that if $G$ is nilpotent, and $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group, then $[G,G]$ is a $p$-group. The paper is beyond me though, I just saw the result there. So the claim holds with the assumption that $G$ is nilpotent. And like Derek Holt says, when $G/Z(G)$ is finite (Schur's theorem). So far I haven't found anything about the general case

Comment: @ Derek Holt: $G/H$ is finite by Lagrange's theorem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)

Comment: It implies that $G/H$ is finite $p$-group

Comment: @chuyenvien94: Lagrange's theorem can only be applied to finite groups! The question makes sense without assuming that $G/H$ is finite. It could be a Tarski Monster, for example, and I have no idea what the answer to the question would be in that case.

Comment: @ Derek Holt: Okay I will edit the first post

Comment: @Derek Holt : This tantamounts to proving that $[G,G]\cap Z(G)$ is a p-group.  One should ask, is it true that every stem extension of an infinite $p$-group is a $p$-group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $H \subseteq Z(G) \subseteq G$, it follows that $G/Z(G) \cong (G/H)/(Z(G)/H)$ is a $p$-group. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then $PZ(G)/Z(G) = G/Z(G)$. So $G=PZ(G)$ and it follows that $[G,G]=[P,P]$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster: Why $G=PZ(G)$ follows that $[G,G]=[P,P]$ is $p$-group. Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: @chuyenvien94: every element $x$ of $G$ can be expressed as $x=uz$ with $u \in P$ and $z \in Z(G)$.  It follows that any commutator of $G$, $[x,x']=[uz,u'z']=[u,u']$ lies in $[P,P]$.

Comment: okay I understood. Thank you.

Comment: @Yassine thanks, I was just about to explain more details.

Comment: Why $P\in Syl_{p}\left(G\right)\Rightarrow PZ(G)/Z(G)=G/Z(G)$. Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$ if $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Since in your case $G/Z(G)$ is a $p$-group itself, the result follows.

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster : you welcome.