# If $G$ is a finite group, $H⊲G$, $G/H$ is finite $p$-group and $H$ cyclic, show that

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, $H⊲G$, $G/H$ is finite $p$-group and $H$ cyclic, show that $H\cap[G,G]\subseteq Z([G,G])$
  and $[[G,G],[G,G]]$
  is $p$
 -group

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: It's an extension of this problem
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538173/if-g-is-a-finite-group-h-vartriangleleft-g-g-h-is-finite-p-group-and

Comment: The first statement follows from the fact that the automorphism group of a cyclic group is abelian, and the second statement can then be proved by applying the result of the previous question to $[G,G]$.

Comment: Since $H$ is cyclic, $H$ is abelian and $H⊆Z(G)$. By http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538173/if-g-is-a-finite-group-h-vartriangleleft-g-g-h-is-finite-p-group-and , $[G,G]$ is $p$-group. $[[G,G],[G,G]]$ is normal in $[G,G]$, so $[[G,G],[G,G]]$ is $p$-group

Comment: But why $H∩[G,G]⊆Z([G,G])$? Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $H \subseteq Z(G)$. As I said before, the automorphism group of a cyclic group is abelian, so $[G,G] \subseteq C_G(H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain what Derek Holt means: $G$ acts on $H$ by conjugation and the kernel of this action is the centralizer $C_G(H)=\{g \in G |  g^{-1}hg=h$, for all $h \in H\}$. This means that $G/C_G(H)$ injects homomorphically in $Aut(H)$ and this last group is abelian, since $H$ is cyclic. So $G'=[G,G] \subseteq C_G(H)$. And hence symmetrically $H \subseteq C_G(G')$, whence $H \cap G' \subseteq Z(G')$.

Now you have reduced it to an earlier question you asked on this site: $G'/(H \cap G') \cong G'H/H$ is a $p$-group, since this is a subgroup of $G/H$. It follows from this [entry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538173/if-g-is-a-finite-group-h-vartriangleleft-g-g-h-is-finite-p-group-and) that $G''$ is a $p$-group too.